# I can't upgrade my .NET to anything over 4.8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've installed multiple .NET SDKs from Microsoft site. They do not appear in Visual Studio when I want to change it. How do I fix this?

I've downloaded SDKs, Nugets, and nothing. I want to be able to use .net 7+ on a C# project.

Comment: .NET Framework stops at 4.8.1 (they said it would be 4.8, but they snuck an update in). The .NET Core lineage, which is .NET Core 1.0 through 3.1 and .NET 5+ (there is no 4.x version in this lineage), installs entirely separately.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to do when "{.Net Core/.Net6/Net7 options} do not appear in Visual Studio"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project is a .NET Framework project (the "older" dot net). You'll not be able to select dotnet 5+ directly in the visual studio project's properties as dotnet net 5+ is the evolution of the dotnet core branch. Those versions will not appear at all.

You can create a new dotnet core project and import your code (and adapt if necessary), or use the tool microsoft released to "upgrade" a .NET Framework project to dotnet core one. (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant)

You'll then be able to select any dotnet core framework you want (ie 7.0)

Answer (score 2):

If your project is targeting .Net framework 4.8, you can't simply upgrade to .Net 7 by selecting from a list,
You need to *migrate* your project to .Net 7,
A very useful tool is the **.Net upgrade assistant** provided by Microsoft.

You can find it here:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant/tutorial/install-sdk

and follow the step-by-step instructions in that page to complete your migration.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing everything related to .NET using the Visual Studio Installer - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads

In order to be able to create .NET 7 application, you will need to select ".NET 7 Runtime" under the "Individual components" section.

[image: Visual Studio Installer interface]

After the installation, you should be able to select ".NET 7" as your application Framework.

[image]

Comment: I have .NET 7 Runtime checked already, however I don't have it.